# Quiz displays wrong score

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build the quiz application with javascipt only but it gives me the wrong score. I first initialised **correct** variable with 0 and then wanted to increment the **correct** variable with 1 every time when the correct answer is selected but it shows the wrong score. I tried really hard to find any error but unable to find one. Please someone help me to fix this code **and I would also appreciate if someone can specify why it is showing the wrong score**.

```js
var questions, question, pos = 0,
  ch1, ch2, ch3, cho, storeval, correct = 0;

questions = [
  ["What is 10 + 4", "12", "14", "16", "B"],
  ["What is 7 x 3", "21", "22", "23", "A"],
  ["What is 20 - 9", "15", "13", "11", "C"],
  ["What is 8/2", "5", "4", "2", "B"]
];

question = document.getElementById('question');


function loadQ() {

  ch1 = questions[pos][1];
  ch2 = questions[pos][2];
  ch3 = questions[pos][3];

  question.innerHTML = questions[pos][0] + "<br>";
  question.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>" + ch1 + "<br>";
  question.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>" + ch2 + "<br>";
  question.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>" + ch3 + "<br>";
}

function submitAnswer() {
  cho = document.getElementsByName('choices');

  for (var i = 0; i < cho.length; i++) {
    if (cho[i].checked) {
      storeval = cho[i].value;
    }
    if (storeval == questions[pos][4]) {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  pos++;

  if (pos < questions.length) {
    loadQ();
  } else {
    question.innerHTML = "Your Score is " + correct;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body onload="loadQ()">
  <div id="customize">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="submitAnswer()" value="Submit">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You said you “tried really hard to find any error”, but it doesn’t look like you’ve used the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and debugged it with `console.log` or `debugger;`. That’s how you find those mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two independent `if` statements in `submitAnswer`. The second one checks whether `storeval == questions[pos][4]`, but this could be an old value of `storeval`, because it doesn’t depend on the first `if` statement to change the value for the current question. Plus, it runs for every input with the potentially wrong value. They should be nested like this:

```
if (cho[i].checked) {
  storeval = cho[i].value;
  if (storeval == questions[pos][4]) {
    correct++;
  }
}
```

---

#### Example

You can actually create live examples by modifying your loop code like this:

```
console.log("The loop is about to be entered. storeval is " + storeval + ".");
for (var i = 0; i < cho.length; i++) {
  console.log("The loop is running for answer " + cho[i].value + ". i is " + i + ".");
  if (cho[i].checked) {
    storeval = cho[i].value;
    console.log(cho[i].value + " is checked! Set storeval to " + storeval + ".");
  }
  if (storeval == questions[pos][4]) {
    correct++;
    console.log("storeval matches the expected question " + storeval + "! Update correct to " + correct + ".");
  }
}
```

Messages beginning with “*X* is checked!” indicate that the first `if` statement is entered. Messages beginning with “`storeval` matches the expected question *X*!” indicate that the second `if` statement is entered.

If you pick the correct answer on the first question, you will get:

> The loop is about to be entered. `storeval` is undefined.
>   The loop is running for answer A. `i` is 0.
>   The loop is running for answer B. `i` is 1.
>   B is checked! Set `storeval` to B.
>   `storeval` matches the expected question B! Update `correct` to 1.
>   The loop is running for answer C. `i` is 2.
>   `storeval` matches the expected question B! Update `correct` to 2.

If you then pick the correct answer on the second question, you will get:

> The loop is about to be entered. `storeval` is B.
>   The loop is running for answer A. `i` is 0.
>   A is checked! Set `storeval` to A.
>   `storeval` matches the expected question A! Update `correct` to 3.
>   The loop is running for answer B. `i` is 1.
>   `storeval` matches the expected question A! Update `correct` to 4.
>   The loop is running for answer C. `i` is 2.
>   `storeval` matches the expected question A! Update `correct` to 5.

Comment: Thanks !
Write now I am in my initial stage to get down with javascript and I know about browser console but could not able to resolve the issue from there, that is why I came here. But I partially understood this code about why it should be nested like this, if possible can you please explain it with an example ?

Comment: Again I really want to thank you for your time. I got the code. Stackoverflow will always going to be awesome if it have people like you. Will going to interact with you in near future with some more knowledge . Thanks again . Take care bud

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the for loop to grab the checked radio replace it with this. Add JQuery to your project it easier.

```
function submitAnswer(){

        storeval = $('input[name=choices]:checked').val();

            if(storeval==questions[pos][4]) {
                correct++;
            }

            pos++;

            if (pos < questions.length){
            loadQ();
            } else  {
                question.innerHTML = "Your Score is " + correct ;
            }
    }
```

Comment: The OP isn’t using jQuery.